# How to select any five from given image and process to next page

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to select any five from given image and process to next page. I am not able to select images and proceed to next page.

[image]

Select and deselect any five

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: [More solutions](https://www.google.com/search?q=use+images+as+checkboxes+site:stackoverflow.com)